# ORDER BY distance to another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, distance

Lets say we have a table like that

```
id|value
--------
1 | 50
2 | 19
3 | 100
4 | 21
5 | -10
```

How can I use `ORDER BY` operator to order values by their distance to another value?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY nearest(value,30) DESC
```

To get this table:

```
id|value
--------
4 | 21
1 | 50
2 | 19
5 | -10
3 | 100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY abs(value - 30) ASC
```

Comment: fix that to SLECT * FROM table ORDER BY abs(value - 30) ASC and i will accept )

Comment: Done. Sorry, I was looking just at your code, not at example. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that all sql dialect accepts answer of Paul92.

Here is another solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT 
      t.*, 
      abs(value - 30) AS abs_value
   FROM table t 
) temp
ORDER BY abs_value
```

Comment: This looks well, but the shorter one did the trick for me on mySql